# Comparing tpl value in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

So I have this **data**:

```
data = [{
    "D": 1,
    "VALID": "N",
    "NUMBER": "7064089-14-1607"
}, {
    "D": 3,
    "VALID": "N",
    "NUMBER": "7064089-24-1106"
}, {
    "D": 5,
    "VALID": "N",
    "NUMBER": "7066097-14-1508"
}]
```

Which is passed to a **store** in extjs.

```
fields: [{name: 'NUMBER', type: 'string'},{name: 'VALID', type: 'string'},{name: 'D', type: 'string'}]
```

Here is my tpl code in **ExtJS**:

```js
tpl: [
'<div class="row">',
    '<div class="column" style="width: 125px">',
        '<h4>NUMBER </h4>',
        '<tpl for =".">',
        '<p>{NUMBER}</p>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</div>',
    '<div class="column" style = "width: 100px">',
        '<h4>VALID </h4>',
        '<tpl for =".">',
        '<p>{VALID}</p>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</div>',
    '<div class="column">',
        '<th></th>',
        '<tpl for =".">',
        '<p>{D}</p>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</div>',
'</div>'
]
```

Is there any way I could put a tpl if inside a tpl for tag if the Value being iterated on D is greater than 1?

For example code to be transferred to `ExtJS` tpl:

```
for i in D:
  if i >1:
    '<td class="gray">i</td>'
  else:
    '<td class="red">i</td>'
```

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean? What does "put a inside a tag" mean?

Answer (score 0):

of course, you can do that, you can use if something like this

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
'<p>Name: {name}</p>',
'<p>Kids: ',
'<tpl for="kids">',
    '<tpl if="age &gt; 1">',
        '<p>{name}</p>',
        '<p>Dad: {parent.name}</p>',
    '</tpl>',
'</tpl></p>'
);
```